# Как правильно рендерить страницы с ошибками в Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Задался этим вопросом, потому что увидел в папке /public Rails проекта файлы 404.html, 422.html и 500.html. Если эти файлы есть, то, по логике, должен быть и определенный способ рендера этих страниц.

Конечно, можно создать в application_controller'е метод типа `render_error(err)`, но мне кажется, что есть более правильный способ.

Попытки типа `render :not_found` или `render "public/404.html"` не увенчались успехом.

Comment: Эти файлы отдает Веб сервер, если от сервера приложений приходит соответствующий HTTP-код ответа. То есть Rails никак не работает с этими файлами.

Comment: @MAXOPKA Но ведь заголовки тоже отдавать можно, насколько я знаю

Comment: @MAXOPKA Да, я был прав: http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails#ispolzovanie-head-dlya-sozdaniya-otklika-soderzhaschego-tolko-zagolovok. Но, к сожалению, возвращение этого заголовка страницу 404 из папки паблик не рендерит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, есть `render file: путь` ([Rails Guides по теме](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-arbitrary-file)).

Во-вторых, есть `send_file` ([документация к Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file)), который пытается послать файл наилучшим доступным способом, т. е. поручая это кому-то ещё, если возможно.

- К примеру, если сервер Rails находится за **nginx**-овым обратным прокси, приложение отвечает не непосредственно клиенту, а на прокси, . Rails-приложение может отдать **пустой** ответ с заголовком `X-Accel-Redirect: путь/к/файлу` и на этом закончить, но **nginx** это заметит, **уберёт** заголовок из ответа, а в теле ответа отдаст указанный файл, самостоятельно, через собственный высокоэффективный IO.

**Но штатный способ отдавать такие нештатные страницы** — через исключения, которые в контроллере никто не поймал. В Rails для этого применяется целая цепочка механизмов.

- На основе **класса** исключения выясняется, какой ответ отдать ([`ExceptionWrapper`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3df3d80ade705dd096ec481845ff0fc2d70427b0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper.rb#L5))
- Ответ отдаётся специальным мини-приложением для Rack ([`ShowExceptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5494af0c0f087a959c7f50e6689ff540cedef130/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L44))
- Мини-приложение [добавляется в стек Rack middleware по умолчанию](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L97) с путём `Rails.public_path`.

...плюс всякие прослойки для настройки.

Т. е. по идее, вам достаточно использовать штатный механизм обработки ошибок в Ruby. **Исключения**. Если надо добавить туда собственные классы исключений, докиньте их в хэш `config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses` в конфигах, [как это делает Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3df3d80ade705dd096ec481845ff0fc2d70427b0/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L19). Или даже напишите свой Rack-обработчик в `config.exceptions_app` *"если у вас есть борода"*.

Comment: Окей. С `render file:` получилось. Действительно, я пытался делать просто `render "public/404.html"`. Про файл забыл. С send_file тоже вроде бы все понятно. Непонятно только насчет исключений. Насколько я понимаю, выбрасывать исключения имеет смысл только в dev окружении. Или нужно как раз-таки писать свой обработчик, который будет рендерить определенную страницу? Ведь тот же ExceptionWrapper при ошибке `:not-found` отдает просто RoutingError.

Comment: @smellyshovel а вот и нет. Бросать надо везде. Обработчики в разных средах будут разные. Проверьте, включите `production`-среду локально.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что выдастся тот самый 404 из папки паблик? Просто сейчас нет возможности проверить.

Comment: @smellyshovel да, именно.

Comment: Буду очень признателен вам, если покажете кодом, как нужно ловить исключение, например в том случае, если попытались найти что-то в БД, не нашли, и, соответственно, выкинули RoutingError (404, так ведь?). Знаю, что через begin - rescue - end. Но как конкретно...

Comment: А то бороды у меня нет :) Стаж не позволяет еще. Да и возраст, раз уж на то пошло :D

Comment: @smellyshovel не, это работает наоборот: вы должны не кинуть исключение нужного типа, а указать, как на исключения определённого типа отвечать. И конкретно RecordNotFound можно просто не ловить. Будет тоже 404. И ни одной строчки кода.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42480/discussion-between-smellyshovel-and-d-side).

Answer (score 1):

Эти файлы не предназначены для рендеринга Рельсой, они используются веб-сервером, когда Рельса кидает исключение. Вы можете "вручную" вызвать исключение, которое интерпретируется как `Record not found`, например: `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: Вы почти продублировали мой ответ, ну да ладно.